# CSS display: table-cell ignores overflow and width

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/

The table cell #t2 does not size correctly:

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="t1">a</div>
    <div id="t2">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
    <div id="t3">a</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#t1{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}
#t2{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: green;
}
#t3{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

How to hide text in `#t2` when it is too long?

Comment: See, this is my desired result and the text of # t2 here is short: http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/1/ if the length of the text exceeds 100% #t2, happens that it lengthens such as here: http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/

Comment: "exceeds 100%" - 100% of WHAT? Herein lies your problem.

Comment: 100% of #t2, see this picture: http://i42.tinypic.com/n1patu.png, I would like this result instead of http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/

Comment: The dots at the end there because the text is too long and cause the elongation of the table, it would not be long 100% as I desire, but more!

Comment: 100% of t2 = t2, it's self-referential. That's why you need to set a maximum width in pixels, not percent.

Comment: I verified your code and even when setting the width through javascript the table-cell display mode blocks off the size adjustment. I also checked if flex-box model would resolve your issue but it seems that this model does not support overflow yet on the subitems. Basically what you're trying to accomplish right now using CSS is impossible. You'll need to use regular block elements and use javascript to determine their size as far as I can see right now.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't want use javascript...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/7/

```
word-break:break-all;
```

Comment: It's not an exact solution but it's the only viable CSS solution. Never used that property before but I'll be sure to remember it now :-)

Answer (score 42):

I had exactly the same problem, and I got a nice solution. Add **table-layout: fixed;** to your id table:

```
#table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Have fun! :D

Comment: Much better (and correct) solution.  For those looking, here are some great use cases: http://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for:-

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to hide the text outside the zone.

or may you can try using this:-

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap; 
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```